# Get number of values that only appear once in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, unique

Firstly, if it is relevant, I'm using MySQL, though I assume a solution would work across DB products. My problem is thus:

I have a simple table with a single column. There are no constraints on the column. Within this column there is some simple data, e.g.

```
a
a
b
c
d
d
```

I need to get the number/count of values that only appear once. From the example above that would be 2 (since only b and c occur once in the column).

Hopefully it's clear I don't want DISTINCT values, but UNIQUE values. I have actually done this before, by creating an additional table with a UNIQUE constraint on the column and simply INSERTing to the new table from the old one, handling the duplicates accordingly.

I was hoping to find a solution that did not require the temporary table, and could somehow just be accomplished with a nifty SELECT.

Comment: LOL at the three similar answer simultaneously posted.

Comment: At this point and after re-reading the question, I actually think Randy or Romain takes the prize, but you did have prettier formatting than me  @Hugh Jones :D

Comment: I did :)  We will probably never know the true meaning of that question - let us move on ...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming your table is called `T` and your field is called `F`:

```
SELECT COUNT(F)
FROM (
    SELECT F
    FROM T
    GROUP BY F
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) AS ONLY_ONCE
```

Comment: For my money - this is the best answer.

Comment: How can i use where in this i.e  "WHERE (created_at BETWEEN '2021-06-01' AND '2021-06-01 23:59:59');".. Coz am getting this error. "unknown column created_at"

Answer (score 4):

```
select count(*) from 
(
  select
    col1, count(*)
  from 
    Table
  group by 
    Col1
  Having 
    Count(Col1) = 1
)
```

Comment: I think my new version is most platform independent

Answer (score 3):

```
select field1, count(field1) from my_table group by field1 having count(field1) = 1

select count(*) from (select field1, count(field1) from my_table group by field1 having count(field1) = 1)
```

first one will return the ones that are unique and second one will return the number of unique elements.

Answer (score 3):

just nest it a little...

```
select count( cnt ) from
( select count(mycol) cnt from mytab group by mycol )
where cnt = 1
```

Comment: The poster, I think, didnt quite put his question right.  This answer addresses a different interpretation from the one all the rest of us made.

Comment: @Hugh - I disagree. Seems very unambiguous to me "I need to get the number/count of values that only appear once. From the example above that would be 2" your answer is simply wrong. This returns the same as Romain's (though it is missing the alias for the derived table)

Comment: Yes - I reread the question and it is not ambiguous, however, 'I dont want DISTINCT values I want UNIQUE ones' sent me the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be as simple as this:

```
Select count(*) From MyTable Group By MyColumn Where Count(MyColumn) = 1
```

Comment: Gives you the list of "uniquely represented" values, but not the count of said values (you'd have to look at the amount of records returned). Good spirit overall, but lacks the top-level count required to answer the question :)

Comment: @Romain Oh sure...technicalities!  Only one out of the group w/no upvotes.  It's like middle-school gym all over again.

Comment: I see what you mean... Hence I was all about highlighting that your answer was actually good... And I'd have up-voted if it had completely answered the question...

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did and it worked:

```
SELECT name 
FROM people JOIN stars ON stars.person_id = people.id 
JOIN movies ON movies.id = stars.movie_id
WHERE year = 2004
GROUP BY name, person_id ORDER BY birth;
```

note: I was working with several tables here.

CS50 Problem Set 7 (pset7) 9.sql fix!!