# How to filter data from SQL that appears only once?

Tags: php, sql

Here is an example of my SQL structure

[image: SQL Example]

As you can see 2 IPs appear only one time each, so I would like to count only these IPs.
I don't want to count any IP address that appear more than once. How can I achieve that ?
I believe the  `COUNT(DISTINCT ip)` will output `4`, but I am expecting `2`

The following code gives total count of rows in last 30 days,

```
$result = $dbh->query('SELECT count(*) as total from data_able WHERE dtime > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)');
$total = $result->fetchColumn();
```

How can I modify it to count unique IPs that appear only 1 time in the last 30 days.

Comment: As clearly explained in the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), do not post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data. No one can copy/paste data from a picture. Sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Comment: perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556713/get-number-of-values-that-only-appear-once-in-a-column) could help

Comment: @Yarin_007 @Stu  The solution in that post gives me an output `1`, I tried with different field also. Is there anything I should change with the PHP code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find those ip's occuring only once, you con do this:

```
SELECT ip FROM data GROUP BY ip HAVING COUNT(ip) = 1;
```

If you want to count them, you can use the first query.

```
SELECT COUNT(ip)
FROM (
SELECT ip
FROM data
GROUP BY ip
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) AS ip;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=df9d835fdc9a7198048e6c271d9ded80)